# AngularJS 2: How to have an 'attribute' directive communicate with its host component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a utility directive in Angular 2, which should collaborate with its host component:

```
<my-component my-directive></my-component>
```

In particular, `my-directive` will watch for certain inputs, then calls certain functions that should be provided by `my-component`. For example, the directive I'm writing would encapsulate the boilerplate for having a component act as a drop-area for a drag-and-drop operation:

```
export const ResourceDropArea = ng.Directive({
    selector: '[resource-drop-area]',
    inputs:   ['data: resourceDropArea'],
    host: {
        '(dragenter)': ' dragenter($event) ',
        '(dragleave)': ' dragleave($event) ',
        '(dragover)':  ' dragover ($event) ',
        '(drop)':      ' drop     ($event) '
    }
}).Class({
    constructor() {}
    // event handling code
});
```

But the component itself would still have to specify what to do when data is dropped on it. That's where I'm having trouble. How do I get a hold of the component object? Or is there a better way?

Oh, and I would much appreciate an ES6 solution (not just Typescript).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection to get the instance of the host component.

```js
export const ResourceDropArea = ng.Directive({ /* ... */ }).Class({

    constructor(myComponent) {
        this.myComponent = myComponent;
    },  

    drop($event) {
        this.myComponent.callSomeMethod();
    }
});

ResourceDropArea.parameters = [MyComponent];
```

Comment: Interesting. But the point of this modularization is that it could be used on any component. So it should call the method on whatever component the directive coincides with. Does the `ResourceDropArea` *need* to know about `MyComponent`? Perhaps I could specify some superclass for `MyComponent` to extend?